# Weird characters appeared in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I was creating java classes in netbeans, and I don't know what button I pressed to make points for placeholder followed by the paragraph markers (¶) appear in my code.
How can I proceed to make them disappear?

[That's what it looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxqxt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try view > Show Non-Printable Characters

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'View' and uncheck the `Show Non-Printable Characters`. That will clears off your problem

`View -> Show Non-printable Characters`

[image: Example]